# How to keep primary human cancer cells alive in vitro and derive a cell line?

Tags: cancer, cell-culture

I am studying a human cohort of patients treated with neoadjuvant immunotherapy before surgery, of whom we have pre- and post-treatment biopsies as well as the resection. In one patient's resection, we discovered a population of less differentiated resistant cancer cells, which excluded immune cells (even though the rest of the lesion was extremely infiltrated). We profiled these by spatial transcriptomics and indeed do find similar cells in our scRNAseq samples of both the pre- and post-treatment biopsies. All very interesting stuff. I'm super curious to figure out how these cancer cells manage to exclude immune cells. The scRNAseq data gives a hundred interesting leads that /could/ reasonably contribute. However, in the end it's lacking experimental support.

Here's the kicker: We still have primary dissociated cells from the pre- and post-treatment biopsy. All cells that weren't used for scRNAseq were frozen in standard freezing media (1 PRE vial, 2 POST). Thus, I essentially have three shots at thawing these cells (pre- and post-treatment biopsy, unless somebody has a tip on how to safely split frozen vials), and attempting to culture and immortalize them. Here comes the issue: Nobody at my institute has experience with this, everybody says that it's hard and with a low chance of success (I somewhat agree). I still think that it's worth a try and that preparation is key here to increase the chance of success.

I am trying to read online resources about primary cancer cell culture (which does seem hard) and also do find various commercial offers of companies that claim good successes with their numbers, but also wanted to turn to the labrats here and ask for advice or hints on where to look/who to ask. So thank you for any and all suggestions!

Comment: Way too broad; there are entire book chapters about this.

Comment: I'd highly recommend finding an experienced collaborator.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks for the suggestion. It crossed my mind before but brings additional complications (which might be too much with the current time constraints)

Comment: It is very hard - you have a tiny chance of success normally. It's been many years since I last did something similar, but IIRC about 1/10^6 cancer cells will grow, but the vast majority of these will not make it to cell line transformation stage. You also have to consider removal of other non-cancer cells from this process; fibroblasts will grow very well under most conditions.

Comment: @immunoLogical My expectation is that the alternative to dealing with those complications, whatever they are, is failure of the attempt at best, and embarrassing or fraudulent results otherwise (e.g., you'll think you were successful but actually you only succeeded in growing some contaminant instead). See bob1's comment as well.